# How to repeat last command in SQLite command prompt in Linux environment?

Tags: linux, sqlite

If I type the up arrow, I am getting '^[[A' this kind of symbols. And by entering that command it gives me same ..> structure all the time, whatever I type after that to leave that space. So, what can I do to get last command I typed before?

```
sqlite> ^[[A
    ...>
    ...>
    ...>
    ...> ;
    ...> .exit
    ...>
```

(I tried everything, including `.exit`)

Only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is working to get me out out sqlite.

Comment: Where did you get your `sqlite3` from? Did you compile it yourself? If yes, how?

Comment: @CL. I am new to SQL and just learning from sqlite command line. I installed it by using `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`.

Comment: Try using rlwrap when launching SQLite. https://superuser.com/questions/82408/sqlite-with-readline-support-on-ubuntu/82447#82447